# VMware workstation unable to start services

Tags: vmware

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 - 64 bit. I installed VMware Workstation 12 and I'm getting this error when I try to run it: (I disabled secure boot with no effect)

```
2018-05-10T21:58:06.537+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Log for VMware Workstation pid=5240 version=12.5.6 build=build-5528349 option=Release
2018-05-10T21:58:06.537+03:00| vthread-4| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.537+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2018-05-10T21:58:06.537+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Host is Linux 4.13.0-41-generic Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
2018-05-10T21:58:06.537+03:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.537+03:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.537+03:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.537+03:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.537+03:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.537+03:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.537+03:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.579+03:00| vthread-4| W115: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-5240.log
2018-05-10T21:58:06.585+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.585+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Created new pathsHash.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.585+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.13.0-41-generic to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include".
2018-05-10T21:58:06.585+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:06.585+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-10T21:58:06.585+03:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.585+03:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-05-10T21:58:06.590+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:06.590+03:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-41-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-10T21:58:06.775+03:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-05-10T21:58:06.775+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.796+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 22206 symbol versions
2018-05-10T21:58:06.796+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.796+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.796+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.796+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.796+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.796+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.796+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-05-10T21:58:06.798+03:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.798+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2018-05-10T21:58:06.799+03:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.799+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2018-05-10T21:58:06.800+03:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.800+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2018-05-10T21:58:06.802+03:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.802+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2018-05-10T21:58:06.803+03:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.818+03:00| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2018-05-10T21:58:06.818+03:00| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2018-05-10T21:58:06.845+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.845+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.13.0-41-generic to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include".
2018-05-10T21:58:06.845+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:06.845+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-10T21:58:06.845+03:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-10T21:58:06.845+03:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-05-10T21:58:06.850+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:06.850+03:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-41-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-10T21:58:07.027+03:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-05-10T21:58:07.027+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.046+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 22206 symbol versions
2018-05-10T21:58:07.047+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include
2018-05-10T21:58:07.047+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include
2018-05-10T21:58:07.047+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.047+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-10T21:58:07.047+03:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.047+03:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-05-10T21:58:07.052+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.052+03:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-41-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-10T21:58:07.053+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2018-05-10T21:58:07.056+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.056+03:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.056+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.058+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.058+03:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.060+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.060+03:00| vthread-4| I125: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.060+03:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.060+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.060+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-10T21:58:07.060+03:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.060+03:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-05-10T21:58:07.066+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.066+03:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-41-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-10T21:58:07.067+03:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.067+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.067+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-10T21:58:07.067+03:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.067+03:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-05-10T21:58:07.074+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.074+03:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-41-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-10T21:58:07.074+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.075+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.075+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.13.0-41-generic to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.075+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.075+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-10T21:58:07.075+03:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.075+03:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-05-10T21:58:07.082+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-41-generic".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.082+03:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-41-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-10T21:58:07.273+03:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-05-10T21:58:07.273+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.292+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 22206 symbol versions
2018-05-10T21:58:07.292+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.294+03:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.294+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.295+03:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.544+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.544+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2018-05-10T21:58:07.549+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2018-05-10T21:58:07.549+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-Or0TQ5/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-05-10T21:58:09.477+03:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2018-05-10T21:58:09.478+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2018-05-10T21:58:09.478+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2018-05-10T21:58:09.483+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2018-05-10T21:58:09.483+03:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-Or0TQ5/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.13.0-41-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-05-10T21:58:13.759+03:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    wget https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/workstation-14.1.1.tar.gz
    tar -xzf workstation-14.1.1.tar.gz
    cd vmware-host-modules-workstation-14.1.1
    sudo make
    sudo make install
```

Comment: still works on 2019.06.06 ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Answer above worked for me, but latest version is 15.1.0

Comment: Worked for 15.5.7